# Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services Handwriting Detection Bounding Box Parameters

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently using [Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services Handwriting Detection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-hand-text).
The API returns a set of values for the bounding box:

```
{
    "boundingBox": [
      2,
      52,
      65,
      46,
      69,
      89,
      7,
      95
    ],
    "text": "dog",
    .
    .
    .
```

I would like to make sense of these 8 parameters. What is their significance and what do they reflect? I tried hard finding about them in Microsoft API's [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200), but of no use. Kindly help me understand what these parameters mean or link me to some place where this doubt can be cleared.
Also let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: can you know how to draw a bounding box with those coordinates? any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure/Computer-Vision-API-OCR-bounding-boxes/td-p/71774), the API returns the four corners of the box in X,Y coordinates. So:

X top left, Y top left, X top right, Y top right, X bottom right, Y bottom right, X bottom left, Y bottom left

Comment: Official reference: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2-preview-1/operations/5d9869604be85dee480c8750

Answer (score 6):

This information is unnecessarily hidden. I finally found it in their [edx course](https://www.edx.org/course/developing-ai-vision-apps-using-microsoft-cognitive-services)

[image]